# “To go bananas” in French / en français

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

***“To go bananas”*** is an expression that is meant to describe a massive loss of self-control, usually caused by anger or an unpleasant surprise, but also sometimes by other types of disturbance that trigger over-excitement or some sort of craziness.

Here is an example from the Wiktionary:

> I just told her she couldn’t have any pudding until after dinner, and **she went bananas**!

How close from this expression can we get in French?

---

***“To go bananas”*** est une expression anglaise destinée à décrire une perte de maîtrise de soi. Habituellement causée par la colère ou par une surprise déplaisante, elle peut aussi survenir après d’autres types de perturbations qui déclenchent une surexcitation ou une comportement un peu fou.

Voici un exemple tiré du Wiktionary, et ma traduction (volontairement) approximative :

> I just told her she couldn’t have any pudding until after dinner, and **she went bananas**!
>
> Je lui ai simplement dit qu’elle ne pourrait pas avoir de pouding après dîner <sub>(**souper** au Québec)</sub> et elle est devenue comme folle.

À quel point pourrait-on s’approcher de cette expression en français ?

Answer (score 6):

Il y a des expressions correspondantes avec le verbe *péter*:

> péter un câble
>
> péter une durite
>
> péter les plombs/un plomb
>
> péter un fusible

Comment: Ainsi que «péter sa coche/péter une coche», commun au Québec :)

Comment: @Greg L'expression consacrée pour _"péter un plomb"_ est plutôt _"péter les plombs"_ selon moi, même si la première reste correcte.

Comment: @Nathan: exact, je vais modifier la réponse. Je serais tenté de penser que "péter les plombs" est l'expression d'origine et a donné "péter un plomb" par calque sur les autres expressions avec "péter".

Comment: @Greg Votre analyse m'a fait penser qu'au Québec, on **saute** une coche (le creux entre les dents d'un engrenage), et que sans doute, par calque aussi, un peu comme vos plombs devenus un seul, on a commencé à la péter, cette coche. En y pensant bien, *péter une coche* est un peu bizarre, bien que communément utilisé.

Comment: Tout ça c'est de la langue de cochon!

Answer (score 5):

Voici une expression au sens proche ayant une petite proximité sémantique...

> Elle est partie en sucette

sinon, toujours avec partir:

> Elle est partie en vrille

Comment: (+1) Très bonne réponse. A noter, variante un peu plus familière mais fréquente également ..."partie en couille". Le verbe partir pouvant lui aussi accepter parfois la variante "barrer en ..."

Comment: @RomainVALERI J'y ai pensé, mais je me suis dit qu'évoquer une proximité sémantique entre une banane et une couille risquait de dépasser les limites du bon goût... :-)

Comment: @jiliagre "fair enough", comme on dit en bon français ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Adding “over” to “to go bananas [over someone/something]” changes its meaning to being crazy about someone in a positive way (raide dingue d’elle/lui?) & for a use of a fruit that apes like perhaps as much as bananas (granted, it's a fruit whose meaning is extended to = “head”), [this old use](https://books.google.com/books?id=4_BgxLq3-AkC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=%22lui+monte+le+coco%22&source=bl&ots=D0CdVEyQun&sig=S5raeaGAKYWav06MN-HkivTBvoI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkrrmzqvTYAhVKuVMKHSMnDsYQ6AEIQDAD#v=onepage&q=%22lui%20monte%20le%20coco%22&f=false) of “[se] monter le coco” could be seen as capturing this “positive” sense of “going crazy/bananas/ape over/about someone/something.”